# Persist the height of a side nav bar for multiple web page sizes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been developing a web site and I'm testing for responsiveness. Everything seems fine but one hurdle that I've been unable to overcome is the side navigation bar height not always being the size of the web site. My application displays additional components based on user selection so the height of the web site can be different.

I've set the css of the navigation bar to have a height of 100% and this is fine for the screen I'm using to develop the site but whenever I change my responsiveness to say 1080p x 720p my side bar doesn't persist to the height of the screen and I'm left with white space (please see photo below).

[image]

My css for the side navigation is as follows:

```
.side-nav {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  width: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00a56b;
  padding-top: 20px; 
}
```

I was considering using media queries to change the percentage of the min-height value for the .side-nav class based on the screen height but is there a more effective way to achieve my goal?

**(EDIT) html div structure:**

```
<!--The main container for the web application-->
<div id="container">
    <!--The header band that will be used throughout the site-->
    <header id="header" class="bottom-border">
        <div id="brand-logo">
            <img id="logo" src="/img/LOGO - SMALL.png" />
            <h1 id="page-header-title"></h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--Left navigation bar that will be available on all pages-->
    <nav class="side-nav">
        <div id="nav-container">
            <p>Navigation</p>
            <a href="#!incident/new" title="New Incident">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> New Incident
            </a>
            <a href="#!incident/search" title="Search Incident">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search Incident
            </a>
            <a href="#!reports" title="Reports">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> Reports
            </a>
            <a href="#!manager" title="Manger Setup">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Manager Setup
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!--Use the angular ng-view attribute, each page will be loaded into this section-->
    <section class="main-content-wrapper">
        <section id="main-content" class="slide-animation" ng-view></section>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way for this type of design using display table

CSS:

```
.parent-div{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.side-nav,
.main-content{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.side-nav{
    width: 240px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #00a56b;
}
.main-content{
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="side-nav"></div>
  <div class="main-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I can't up vote your answer but basically this has resolved my issue. I thought my previous solution (which I've now deleted) was the solution. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css for side navbar

CSS:

```
.side-nav{
    width: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00a56b;
    padding-top: 20px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has not resolved my issue and I'm still seeing white space under my side-nav

Comment: Can you please send html div structure

Comment: I've edited my post and you can now see my div structure. Would the section div have anything to do with the height not being persisted?